# 301 редирект, убрать GET параметры

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

В редиректах не силен, делал по примерам из статей. Итак, делаю 301 редирект со старого сайта (на Kohana) на новый. Прописал

> Redirect 301 /restoran/list/10 https://www.site.com/catalog/restorany/

После перехода получается ссылка https://www.site.com/catalog/restorany/?kohana_uri=/restoran/list/10

Как мне избавиться от GET-параметра после редиректа?

**UPD**

Попробовал [вот так](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=549a935f-a751-577f-aa9b-fcaa205457d4) (после долгих поисков)

> RewriteRule ^restoran/list/11$ https://www.site.com/catalog/restorany/ [L,R=301]

Тестер показывает что редирект правильный, но на сайте не работает.

Comment: флаг `QSD` попробуйте добавить к вашим `[L,R=301]`

Comment: и возможно, `^restoran/list/11$` следует заменить на `^restoran/list/(\d+)$`

Comment: @teran QSD не срабатывает, /list/11 менять не могу, т.к. таких страниц будет порядка 400

Comment: ну дак вам только 11ю страницу перенаправить надо, или все?

Comment: все страницы, но у каждого числа свой текстовый аналог на новом сайте

Comment: и вы хотите 400 правил редиректа написать что ли? сомнительное решение

Comment: @teran учитывая, что приехало ЧПУ, другого не вижу

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось проще некуда:

> Редиректы нужно ставить выше правил ЧПУ **RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1**

Оставлю здесь, если сообщество посчитает вопрос мусорным, то можно и удалить его.